# Unable to flag posts on historically locked questions

Tags: discussion

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84556/142162) with an [image answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170738/142162) that does not exist anymore.  Due to the question being locked, I cannot flag the answer for removal.

Could this answer be removed?

**Edit**:

- [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85581/142162)
- [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658364/142162)
- [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/90074/142162)
- [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119521/142162)
- [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626249/142162)
- [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/810316/142162)
- [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275206/142162)

Comment: Can we now delete that question? Please? I mean, I like it as much as everyone else...but pretty please?

Comment: We don't do significant edits that change the entire meaning of the post.  If you do it again, we'll lock this post.  If you want to delete the specific questions, then bring it up as a *separate question*.  SO rules still apply (for the most part) here (even though they are a little bit more lax).  Also, use one question on meta per question and tag it `specific-question`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed that for you.  Moderators can still delete posts on locked questions.  I've deleted those answers for now.

This question was created *way* before imgur came into the picture at Stack Overflow so there's probably a number of broken images out there.

If you have a copy (and the rights) of the image I'd recommend uploading it to imgur (through the image box on the page) so it's stored there for posterity and then bringing it up on meta with the link to the image and we'll restore the answer on the post with the working image link.

Comment: You missed...that delete button you're looking for is close to the top of the page, a little bit underneath the question text.

Comment: There was a significant edit in the question, it's now asking for the question to be deleted... Could you please?

Comment: Missed [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/91638/59303)

Comment: @ChrisF Fixed..

Comment: @Kobobby That should be a separate question.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast That should be a separate question.  This is about broken answers on that question.

Comment: @casperOne: the broken answers are merely a symptom. You could have solved it by deleting the whole question :)

Comment: @sixlettervariables Yes, and create how many other problems in the process?  I'm not saying if I'm for or against, but if you want a question deleted, then make a post getting the community's reaction.  Even if the community agrees with the deletion, SE might keep it up under the mandate that it would "break" the internet given there are too many inbound links to it.

Comment: @casperOne: we're not the Wayback Machine. *(besides I was just baiting the Bike Shed Conservationists)*

Comment: @Won't What, I have to choose?  YOU choose.

Comment: What about [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227/21471) one? There is a dead image. I can't either edit or flag it. The image is on stack imgur, but still missing.

Comment: @kenorb I'm not a mod on unix.se nor do I have edit permissions, I suggest you ask one of the mods there to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the lock just to remove a single answer (or ten) is a bit of a hassle, not really worth it.

Deleting the question on the other hand...

Comment: Can't we just migrate it to programmers ;)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Count me in.

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually that's a great idea, that beast will be a lot easier to kill on Programmers...

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm pretty sure our children will know this moment as "the beginning of the Stack Exchange Civil War"...

Comment: @DanielFischer "Programmers... appears to be degrading into fairly stupid water-cooler nonsense..." ([Joel's blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/ "written in Sep 2010"))

Comment: @DanielFischer - no. It was resked and deleted - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-is-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - you should know better

Comment: @ChrisF Okay, I give up. Were you being serious or was that the awesomest deadpan I've seen in years?